# msiexec silent install will fail without error

Tags: windows, windows-installer

On Windows 10, I have tried to do a silent install of an msi package, but the install simply fails without any error.

Here are my commands to get the msi in zip format, unzip, and then install.

```
wget -q http://kakadusoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi_.zip
cmake -E tar -xf KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi_.zip
msiexec /i KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi /quiet /qn /norestart
```

Edit: I logged output to file, and found this error

```
MSI (s) (64:AC) [09:15:20:332]: Product: Kakadu Demo-Apps -- Error 1925. You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine.  Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.
```

Comment: Are you doing it from an elevated prompt? If your MSI needs to modify any protected registry settings (HKLM, HKCR) or protected directories (c:\program files, c:\windows) then the silent install will fail unless run under an elevated process. Also, you need both /quiet and /qn ? Are they redundant?

Comment: Thanks, that is possible. I am running this in a github action, btw. And you are correct, the /quiet is redundant

Comment: You can log the results of the installer...which might be useful when it's failing. Having a redundant option might make msiexec barf...idk.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Installer is a "Windows application" (as opposed to a "console application") which means starting it from the command-line will not cause the console to wait. To wait, you need to explicitly wait for the process to exit. One easy way is:

```
start /wait "" msiexec /i KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi /qn /norestart
```

Note: The empty string `""` is important if you ever need to quote the command-line to start. Otherwise, the `start` command will use your quoted command-line as the title of the created window (crazy, I know, check `start /?` for the details).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue - it still silently fails.